YouTube captions not showing on my primary Google account
Captions on YouTube aren’t showing up when I use my primary Google account on my Surface. If I switch to a different Google account, captions work fine. I’ve tried clearing cache, reinstalling Chrome, and checking settings, but the issue persists only with this one account. Any suggestions?

May be a transient bug. See this similar issue from a year ago "Closed captions not working?" (r/youtube)
